# Session variable works on local server, but not on hosting server

Tags: php, session-variables

I am developing a simple php/mysql discussion forum. The statement

```
<?php print $_SESSION['username']; ?>
```

produces the desired results on my local machine, but when I uploaded the code to test the forum live, the value of the session variable no longer displayed. What could be causing this?

Comment: Have you stated `session_start();` at the beginning of your code?

Comment: check your phpinfo() output to make sure sessions are supported on your server and that writes are permitted to wherever it saves session data.

Answer (score 2):

one thing that can cause this is if the live web server is on a load balanced environment using default php session handling. By default php stores session data in a flat file on ther server so if the user is jumping around webheads they will lose session data.

in that case you will need to define your own session handler using a db

Comment: I have started my session ... everything works fine with the session variables on my local server, just not when I upload it. I don't understand what you mean by "if the user is jumping around webheads they will lose session data.'  If this is what has happened in my case, how do I define my own session handler using a db?

Comment: If it makes any difference, I printed out my three session variables: user_id (int), username (string) and admin (int). The values of the two integer session variables were begin picked up fine ... it was 'username', the string, that was not being displayed.

Comment: first you would need to create a DB table to store a users session. Then you would need to create a class that defines all the session handler functions and gets and sets the data in your db. Then when you call session_start() it will save and retrieve from the central  database rather than a flat file on whatever server you are on.

Comment: as far as you not knowing what "if the user is jumping around webheads they will lose session data.'. In a load balanced environment  web connections are not handled by a single web server. The load is shared by multiple servers. If the session is started on webserver1 and the session gets stored in /tmp/sessionid then the user changes a page and gets sent to webserver2 the 2nd web server has no knowledge of the first so cannot access the previously created session.

Comment: you would also need to change the php config entry for session.save_handler from files to user.