# Cakephp After redirecting session is not working in Live server

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am using cakephp 2.0 in My Users controller i am setting a SESSION in **login** action using

> $this->Session->write('Users',$value);

once session set it will redirect to next action named **home**. In login action its working I logged and checked the value, but after the redirect I read the session value by using the following in **home** action

> $this->log($this->Session->read('Users'));

nothing displayed. But its working fine in local server.

Comment: Set the debug mode to '2' in app/Config/core.php and check, is there any warning it shows or something else?

Comment: May be this will helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720795/session-variable-works-on-local-server-but-not-on-hosting-server

Comment: I have faced same problem because of extra whitespace after ?>
can you set output_buffering=Off and check whether you have that extra   whitespaces or not?

Comment: yes i try that.. there is no space in my files..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the following things on your server.

- Check your php.ini file whether session is enabled or not.
- session.cookie.domain is set to your server or not.
- Check for your php files having any blank lines after `?>` if any please remove.

And then try.

Comment: Thank you Vins.. finally I got thats Session.cookie_domain is set as different server name so only the issue

Answer (score 1):

What I understood is:
You are writing the session value into a log file. The value will not display on the screen, instead of it you can find this value in `app/tmp/logs/error.log` file.

[This link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#using-the-default-filelog-class) will help you to get understand the concept.

To display the session value use `pr($this->Session->read('Users'));`

Kindly ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: nope i done like this pr($this->Session->read('Users')); already. i logging so i put that lines

Comment: also i am checking this app/tmp/logs/error.log file so only i wrote $this->log($this->Session->read('Users'));

Comment: delete your cache files from `app/tmp/cache` and check.

Answer (score 0):

User cakephp `debug toolkit` to check the session values. By using this you'll be able to monitor many things like

- Request History.
- Session.
- Sql Log.
- Timer.
- Log (Which you are using in your question).
- Variable set to your view.

https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/ Different version of debug kit are available for different version of Cake.